# Why doesn't Ryder use the meteor to give himself abilities?

Tags: paw-patrol, mighty-pups

In *Mighty Pups*, Ryder isn't in the vicinity of the meteor when it gives off its "energy burst" that grants super powers.

Ryder builds himself a super-powered flying suit instead to "keep up" with the pups. Eventually, the pups lose their abilities.

But later in the series, Ryder figures out how to tap into the meteor to give the pups their super powers at will.

We also know the meteor works on humans, as it grants powers to Harold Humdinger, Ladybird, etc.

So why doesn't Ryder ever grant himself super powers during Mighty Pup missions? Instead, he always continues to use his super suit.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any particular guarantee that if he gives himself powers, that flight will be one of them.

Comment: I agree. No reason he wouldn't use the suit with his own powers. As you're abilities seem to be at least somewhat based on your natural abilities and personality, I would expect Ryder's powers to be closer to Harold's or Rocky's.

Answer (score -1):

Even If it doesn't give ryder the ability of flight it probably will help him keep up with the pups maybe depending on the superpower of course. Also for some reason I felt like before the copycat existed that ryder would probably have those same powers but where the powers are stronger when all the Mighty pups are nearby and when they get farther the powers would probably get weaker and weaker. For Ryder not the "Copycat" that is.
Maybe he doesn't want to use it because of what happend to mayor humdinger could possibly happen to him in a different way, I don't know.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  But that's if he uses it.  Why doesn't he use it?  Please make sure what you're posting is actually an answer to the question that was asked.  You might want to take the [tour].